# If/else statement using column names in R

Tags: r

I want to do an ifelse function here pulling from an existing df "Tokens" a column name called "Vowel" to create column name "Ambiguity".

If column "Vowel" contains "o" or "u", I want to create a column called "High.Ambiguity", and put the value "1"; else, put "0".

What would the syntax for this look like?

Comment: please provide the example code to generate the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the trick for you. `mutate` creates a new column, in this case called `High.Ambiguity` which takes on the value 1 when `Vowel` (a column in `Tokens`) is either 'o' or 'u' otherwise it is 0.

```r
library(dplyr)
Tokens <- Tokens %>%
  mutate(High.Ambiguity = ifelse(Vowel %in% c("o", "u"), 1, 0))
```